# How to add the same texture to every face individually

Tags: texturing, uv

I want to make a ground and add a grass texture to every single face(I already subdivided it). If i apply the texture it goes over the whole plain but I want the texture for every face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either uv map individual parts to tiles within your texture or create several materials, select your faces and then click the "assign" button under the objects material list.

Uv mapping :

[image]

or

Assign :

[image]

Comment: sorry, understood now

Comment: You shouldn't use destructive operations if you haven't even started doing proper uv mapping/assigning. You have to select your faces or else try [uv project modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html) . Alternatively you could do a top down uv projection and look into [splatmaps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sn8Zhif4LE) instead.